# Scons command with time limit

Tags: scons

I want to limit the execution time of a program I am running under Linux. I put in my scons script a line like:

```
Command("com​","",​"ulimit -t 1; myprogram")
```

and tested it with an infinite loop program: it did not work and the program ran forever.

Am I missing something?

-- tsf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ulimit -t 1` means that the limit is set to 1 second of CPU time. If your infinite loop program uses any sort of `sleep` in its inner loop then it will use practically no CPU time. This means it will not get killed in 1 second of real, on the clock time. In fact it may take minutes or hours to use up its 1 second allocation.

What happens if you run the command outside of SCons? Perhaps you don't have permission to change the limit at all...

```
ulimit -t 1; ./myprogram
```

For example, it may say the following if the limit is already set to 0:

```
bash: ulimit: cpu time: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Edit: it seems that [the -t option is broken on Ubuntu 9.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jaunty/+source/linux/+bug/361508). A fix has been committed 05 June 2009, but it may take a while to trickle into the updates - it may not be fixed until 9.10.

As an historical note, this problem no longer exists in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: My program endless loop was something like (in C):

   while (1)
        x = 1;

so that that there was no sleep in it.

-- tsf

Comment: It seems that this is not a problem of Scons! I tried 

   ulimit -t 1; ./myprogram

It worked (was interrupted) under a Linux Fedora installation but did not work under Ubuntu. I have to check whether it depends on some configuration value.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I was trying it on openSuse and it worked. On Ubuntu... nothing. No error but no kill after 1 second either.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this script:

(taken from http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.mac.system/2005-12/msg00247.html)

```
#!/bin/sh
# timeout script
#
usage()
{
echo "usage: timeout seconds command args ..."
exit 1
}

[[ $# -lt 2 ]] && usage
seconds=$1; shift

timeout()
{
sleep $seconds
kill -9 $pid >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}

eval "$@" &
pid=$!
timeout &
wait $pid
.
```